# resultSet.updateRow() now how do i get the row/position curser at new row?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I want to find the primary key of the newly created row using resultSet.updateRow()

I have tried

```
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateString( 2, path );
                rs.insertRow();
                updated++;
                rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
                if (rs == null)return updated;//evals to true always
                rs.next();

                // This is where I want the primary key
                id = rs.getInt(1);
```

also:

```
                rs.last()//no current row exception
                id = rs.getInt(1);
```

is there an easy way or do I need to create another query?

Answer (score 0):

And you have created a primary key column which is auto-generated?
Does it work if you do a normal insert (not using an updatable rs)?